# Python interpreter crash from within WingIDE

Tags: python, crash, interpreter, wing-ide

When I am trying to run my python test from within WingIDE setup, its always crashing with the following message

```
Fatal Python error: GC object already tracked

This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
Please contact the application's support team for more information.
Fatal Python erDeviceFind: Failed scanning the PCI bus.
Error: 0x2000000f - Device not found
```

But when i run the same script from command prompt (python environment setup), the script runs fine without any crash!
Any suggestions which might point what might be going wrong?

[Edit]: When i tried WinDbg to investigate what might be going wrong, i got the following stack trace:

```
0:000> ~*kb

.  0  Id: 14e0.1708 Suspend: 0 Teb: 7ffdf000 Unfrozen
ChildEBP RetAddr  Args to Child              
0021e78c 77106914 7711e1a7 ffffffff 00000003 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
0021e790 7711e1a7 ffffffff 00000003 00000000 ntdll!ZwTerminateProcess+0xc
0021e7ac 75e4bbf6 00000000 77e8f3b0 ffffffff ntdll!RtlExitUserProcess+0x85
0021e7c0 7c348d03 00000003 7c3476c9 00000003 kernel32!ExitProcessStub+0x12
0021e7c8 7c3476c8 00000003 00000000 7c391300 MSVCR71!__crtExitProcess+0x2e [f:\vs70builds\3052\vc\crtbld\crt\src\crt0dat.c @ 463]
0021e7f8 7c348d22 00000003 00000001 00000000 MSVCR71!doexit+0xab [f:\vs70builds\3052\vc\crtbld\crt\src\crt0dat.c @ 414]
0021e808 7c34d2b1 00000003 1e164d28 75e2f138 MSVCR71!_exit+0xd [f:\vs70builds\3052\vc\crtbld\crt\src\crt0dat.c @ 311]
0021e850 7c34cf8a 00000016 00000095 06cbf3e0 MSVCR71!raise+0xae [f:\vs70builds\3052\vc\crtbld\crt\src\winsig.c @ 508]
*** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for C:\Windows\system32\python24.dll
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for C:\Windows\system32\python24.dll - 
0021e864 1e0a9c6d 1e164d28 06dec458 020671d2 MSVCR71!abort+0xe [f:\vs70builds\3052\vc\crtbld\crt\src\abort.c @ 48]
WARNING: Stack unwind information not available. Following frames may be wrong.
0021e878 1e0290a4 00000002 021146cc 00000002 python24!PyTuple_New+0x9d
0021e8e0 1e029e29 1e02a49c 01aead28 02109540 python24!PyEval_EvalFrame+0x1764
0021e8e4 1e02a49c 01aead28 02109540 00000002 python24!PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x49
0021e918 1e026576 021102a0 00000002 00000000 python24!PyEval_EvalCodeEx+0x6bc
0021e954 1e027736 0021e9bc 00000002 00000000 python24!PyEval_GetFuncDesc+0x176
0021e980 1e029477 0021e9bc 00000000 00000002 python24!PyEval_CallObject+0x326
0021e9c0 7c3496a2 0210b160 02223384 00000002 python24!PyEval_EvalFrame+0x1b37
0021e9ec 1e02651b 02223218 00000000 00000002 MSVCR71!_getptd+0x6c [f:\vs70builds\3052\vc\crtbld\crt\src\tidtable.c @ 319]
0021ea04 1e027736 0021ea6c 00000002 00000000 python24!PyEval_GetFuncDesc+0x11b
0021ea30 1e029477 0021ea6c 00000000 00000003 python24!PyEval_CallObject+0x326
0021ea70 1e05e499 0210b1e0 021d9490 00000003 python24!PyEval_EvalFrame+0x1b37
0021ea9c 1e02651b 021d9330 00000000 00000003 python24!PyFrame_New+0xb9
00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 python24!PyEval_GetFuncDesc+0x11b
```

I could find some related/similar crash (on interpreter launched from another process), on the web, but that wasn't of much help either.
Hope the stack trace might point at something useful, which i might be missing

Comment: If this code works outside of Wing's debugger, can you please send a sample that replicates the problem to support@wingware.com or post it here?  The problem requires seeing what code triggers it, or at least it isn't anything we've seen before and thus probably not a general problem w/ the debugger implementation.  Also please include details like Wing IDE version and Python version that you are using.

Comment: WingIDE : I tried with WingIDE 5 Pro(beta) as well as WingIDE 4.1 Pro. Python version : Python 2.4

Comment: Looks like no debugger code is on the stack so that doesn't reveal much, unfortunately.  I think the next step is to try to create a small test case we can try here.  Note that Python 2.4 is pretty ancient and may have quite a few bugs in it, particularly on newer Windows versions.  In fact Wing 5 doesn't support it at all, so that certainly won't work.

Comment: The problem doesn't seem to happen if I configure external console (and use python.exe console) as DebugIO window from WingIDE. Problem is solved for me atleast for now :)